# how can i embed social media code using ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

### Actually i am using **version 4**, and when i insert **`embed code`** youtube, facebook, instagram, twitter, it does not show me proper preview means it only shows content not containing video, gif etc

Comment: atleast please provide that embed code

Comment: It's hard to offer a solution without seeing an example of your code.